# Using find recursively and only returning the matching file names

Tags: grep, find

I am trying to find all instances of a string within files - I am using find and it works great, however, it returns not only the file but every instance of that string within the file which results in a huge long list whereas I really only want the file name.

I am using:

```
find . -name '*.php' -exec grep -i 'MATCH' {} \; -print
```

This will show me every instance of MATCH and then the file name then the next batch and the filename so something like:

```
MATCH
MATCH
MATCH
./filename
MATCH
MATCH
MATCH
./filename2
```

I tried changing GREP to:

```
find . -name '*.php' -exec grep -H -i 'MATCH' {} \; -print
```

and this then gave me:

```
./filename: MATCH
./filename: MATCH
./filename: MATCH
./filename2: MATCH
./filename2: MATCH
./filename2: MATCH
```

however this still results in the same number of lines being shown all be it slightly differently laid out.

I tried changing GREP to:

```
find . -name '*.php' -exec grep -l -i 'MATCH' {} \; -print
```

and this then gave me:

```
./filename
./filename
./filename
./filename2
./filename2
./filename2
```

Ideally I would like something like:

```
./filename
./filename2
```

which only lists each of the file which match once regardless of how many times it appears in each file - can this be done?

Answer (score 2):

Use the features provided by grep:

> -l, --files-with-matches  print only names of FILEs containing matches
>   -R, -r, --recursive       equivalent to --directories=recurse
>   --include=FILE_PATTERN  search only files that match FILE_PATTERN
>   -i, --ignore-case         ignore case distinctions

I.e.

```
grep -ril --include="*.php" 'MATCH' .
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not the `grep` that's the problem, you're **telling** `find` to print every file name:

```
find . -name '*.php' -exec grep -l -i 'MATCH' {} \; -print
```

Note the `-print` at the end. Just remove that:

```
find . -name '*.php' -exec grep -l -i 'MATCH' {} \;
```

Look:

```
$ echo 'foo' > file1

$ echo 'foo' > file2

$ find . -name 'file*' -exec grep -l -i foo {} \; -print
./file1
./file1
./file2
./file2

$ find . -name 'file*' -exec grep -l -i foo {} \;
./file1
./file2
```